# Consider defining a bean of type 'redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool' in your configuration. error while integrating Redis Jedis

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis

I am implementing Redis Jedis with spring boot application. I am using below dependency and configuration.
while doing this i am getting error "**Consider defining a bean of type 'redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool' in your configuration.**"

While reading the redis host, port and password from yml manually then it works fine. But since i am using **spring-boot-starter-data-redis** dependency so i do not want to read the redis host, port, password from yml file in fact it should work with @configuration and @bean automatically. In fact Redis Lettuce also woking with autoconfigyration fine but Redis Jedis is not. Please help.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
            <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and below is my configuration file

```
@Configuration public class SchedulerConfiguration
{
    @Bean public LockProvider lockProvider(JedisPool jedisPool)
    {
        return new JedisLockProvider(jedisPool);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to configure Spring to use the `Redis` and should use the `RedisTemplate` when using `spring-data-redis`. Using the template provides easy configurations and enables quick setup and use redis in the Spring applications.

Here's how the configuration should look like if you are using annotation based configurations

```
package test;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericToStringSerializer;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("test") // Component Scan Base Package
public class RedisConfiguration{

    // Better if you can use a properties file and inject these values
    private String redisHost = "localhost";
    private int redisPort = 6379;

    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        JedisConnectionFactory factory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHostName(redisHost);
        factory.setPort(redisPort);
        factory.setUsePool(true);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    RedisTemplate< String, Object > redisTemplate() {
        final RedisTemplate< String, Object > template =  new RedisTemplate< String, Object >();
        template.setConnectionFactory( jedisConnectionFactory() );
        template.setKeySerializer( new StringRedisSerializer() );
        template.setHashValueSerializer( new GenericToStringSerializer< Object >( Object.class ) );
        template.setValueSerializer( new GenericToStringSerializer< Object >( Object.class ) );
        return template;
    }
}
```

And then use within a service

```
@Service
public class RedisService {

    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate< String, Object > template;

    // Methods to add and get objects from redis goes here
}
```

And finally, the main class,

```
public class MainClassTest{

    public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(RedisConfiguration.class);
        RedisService redisService = context.getBean(RedisService.class);
        // Use the service here
    }
}
```

Comment: i have to use  public LockProvider lockProvider(JedisPool jedisPool) only Rest others are working fine. Infact above one you shared that is also working, and public LockProvider lockProvider(RedisConnectionFactory  connectionFactory) is also working. But i do not know know why Jedispool is not working.

Comment: As the exception suggest, have you tried defining a bean with JedisPool `@Bean
    JedisPool jedisPool()
    {
        return new JedisPool( new JedisPoolConfig(), "localhost", 6379 );
    }`

Comment: thank you it is working fine now. Can you please suggest to read host, port and password from yml file pick these values automatically in place of defining it manual.

Comment: @Krishna Please mark the answer as an accepted answer if it helped you to solve the problem. As for the your next question, rather than using a yml, follow the above answer and read the host port and password via a properties file. Ofcourse reading through a yml is also possible, but have to go through some extra steps of parsing the yml to a java object and then getting the required values